# REACT NATIVE: Correct syntax for adding a Provider component within the return statement of my App.JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, syntax

What is the correct syntax for adding a Provider tag with a store prop within a return statement of the App.js, when there is already a navigation container in the return?

I tried wrapping the Provider component around my navigation container and drawers, but I don't think that is correct.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
          <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Adoption Page' component={AdoptionPage} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Bunny Treats' component={BunnyTreats} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Contact Us' component={ContactForm} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Cart' component={Cart} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#step-3-provide-the-context.